# Getting garbage while dereferencing a char value with int type pointer

Tags: c

why the data type of variable and its pointer  should be same in c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char testvar = 9;
    int * testptr = &testvar;
    printf("testvar = %d", *testptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Its printing garbage value why ??

Comment: You're initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'char *'...

Comment: You invoke _undefined behaviour_ and the name already describes it perfectly. You find more information on that and why using correct types in any C book. And pay heed to compiler warnings.

Comment: Whatever was wrong with the simple `printf("testvar = %d", testvar);` which promotes the `char` to `int`?

Answer (score -1):

You intitialized one byte and printed four, so the other three of them are something arbitrary.

Try this:

```
int testvar = 9;
```

That will initialize four bytes.

Or this:

```
char testvar = 9;
char dummy1 = 0;
char dummy2 = 0;
char dummy3 = 0;

int * p = (int *)& testvar;
```

Depending on how the stack is laid out that may get you what you want (depending on platform and compiler and optimization). **It's very, very bad programming practice. Don't *ever* do this sort of thing in production code.**

Don't do it in your homework either. It's the kind of thing you play with just to see what happens when you're learning how pointers work.

Comment: @xetra But are they in the order I expect, or the reverse?

Comment: well Im sure it is...semantically it would be a too great impact if it would reverse the adress order... but tbh now im not sure anymore as more I think about it. damn coding :D

Comment: This is non-portable, and breaks the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, too. There is no requirement by the standard an implementation has to use a stack at all (and a typeical compiler will not even allocate space for the `dummy` variables, as they are not used). Even iff they exist, it is not guaranteed they are adjascent on the stack or there is no padding in-between. **Don't use such hacks!**

Comment: @EdPlunkett Not only could they be in reverse order, they could be in any random order, with any number of padding bytes in between. And they could also be assigned to registers, or completely optimized out, so not on the stack at all. In other words, this answer is complete rubbish. (Not my DV BTW.)

Comment: @user3386109 Updated my answer to help people understand that I wasn't advocating that as a programming technique. I'd hate for OP to think I was. OTOH I find it strangely exhilarating that people who know enough to be horrified thought I meant it that way.

Comment: Ok, that looks better. But sometimes the right answer is just, "Don't do that."

Comment: @user3386109 I think you can't learn pointers by rote. Not well enough to be trusted with them, anyway.

Comment: @Olaf See update. Not recommending people write code that way.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: It is not just "bad practice", but plain nonsense, as there is no guarantee given about any layout/placement, etc. Some thing like accessing a `struct` member beyound its space into the next menber would be bad practice, but not the one shown in the question.

Comment: @Olaf Right, all kinds of stuff can happen. Hence "see what happens".

Comment: @Olaf I don't think it'll break his computer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Maybe not if he has protected memory. But on e.g. an embedded system it literally can. Also this is a typical way malware works. And I hopy you don't doubt some of this **does** break computers.

Comment: @Olaf I don't think OP is very likely to be doing his homework on the elevator controller in his building (God, I hope not), and you can't refuse to teach people C just because some small percentage are unethical. Anyhow, based on OPs question, how likely do you think it is that he even *could* be dangerous any time soon?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I don't try to keep you from teaching. But that is just way too wrong (sorry, lacking a better phrase) and too prone to fail with a normal compiler.